# Handling of Future.failure in a Diode effect

Tags: scala, diode

In Diode, how do one handle a Future.failure in an effect?
The doc (https://ochrons.github.io/diode/usage/Effects.html), it is clear how a success value from the Ajax call is used to update the model with a Pot.Ready, but I wonder how one can catch a failure and update a Pot.Failed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain effects, you need to transform both successful `Future` and a failed `Future` into a suitable action using a combination of `map` and `recover`. For example:

```
val eff = Effect(Ajax.get(url)
  .map(r => NewMessages(r.responseText)))
  .recover { case e => MessageLoadingFailed(e.getMessage) }
)
```

If you are using `AsyncAction` (or the derived `PotAction`) it provides a helper method `effect` that automatically handles future failure and creates a `PotFailed` state.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers Ochrons =)